# Get the value of an entry created with a button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am new to python tkinter.I would like to get some help from you.
After adding a few entries with the button (`Add_button`), then entering a value to each of them, I would like to know how I can get the value from those entries and add them up.
I tried a few things, they did not work.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()


s=0
def add_button():
    global s
    s +=1
    for i in range(s):
        lab1=Label(root, text='lab1')
        lab1.grid(row=i, column=1)
        entry1=Entry(root)
        entry1.grid(row=i, column=2)
        
        

bouton_add=Button(root, text='Create widget', command=add_button )
bouton_add.grid(row=5, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

a=[]
s=0
def add_button():
    global s
    s +=1
    lab1=Label(root, text=f'lab{s}')
    lab1.grid(row=s, column=0)
    entry1=Entry(root)
    a.append(entry1)
    entry1.grid(row=s, column=1)
        
def get_entry():
    a_data=[]
    for i in a:

        a_data.append(i.get())
    print(a_data)

bouton_add=Button(root, text='Create widget', command=add_button )
bouton_add.grid(row=5, column=0)


bouton_add=Button(root, text='get', command=get_entry )
bouton_add.grid(row=5, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

The for-loop with range(s) would create a new entry over the previous entry, so even if you use the `get_entry` method, you will get result on previous entry as '' only.

I have just stored references to the entry when they are create in a list, and to get their value, used a for loop for elements in the list `a`, and used `.get` method to get thier value.

Answer (score 0):

> After adding a few entries with the button (Add_button), then entering
> a value to each of them, I would like to know how I can get the value
> from those entries and add them up.

Add two function one for `new_element` method and one for `summing` method.

Following add widgets:

- new_entry
- label_new_entry
- label_answer
- button_add
- button_sum

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title(f'Add Sum of Entry')
 
column_number = 0
list_number = []

def new_element():
    global column_number  
    column_number +=1
         
    new_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=10)       
    new_entry.grid(row=1,column=column_number)
    list_number.append(new_entry)

def summing():
    add_sum = 0
    for list_numbers in list_number:
        add_sum += float(list_numbers.get())
        print(add_sum)
 
    label_answer.config(text=add_sum)
    
   
label_new_entry = tk.Label(root, text="New Entry")       
label_new_entry.grid(row=0, column=column_number)

label_answer = tk.Label(root)
label_answer.grid(row=5,column=column_number)

button_add = tk.Button(root, text="add", command=new_element)
button_add.grid(row=2,column=1, pady=10)

button_sum = tk.Button(root, text="sum", command=summing)
button_sum.grid(row=2,column=2, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]